# Shinydashboard skin effect is not working after renderUI

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I am trying to render shinydashboard after login page but shinydashboard skin color is not showing.
my code is as follow:

**ui.r**

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
uiOutput("page")
```

**Login.R**

```
 library(shinydashboard)

ui1Output <-  function(id, label = "ui1") {

  shinyUI(fluidPage(
                      mainPanel( 

                              textInput("username","Username",placeholder ="UserName"),
                              passwordInput("password","Password", placeholder ="Password"),
                              actionButton("login", "Login")
                             )))
  }
```

**dashbaordpage.R**

```
library(shinydashboard)
 dashpageOutput <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",h2("Dashbaord")),

      # Second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
              h2("Widgets tab content")
      )
    )
  )
```

**global.R**

```
source('login.R') #login page
source('dashboardPage.R')#dashbaordpage
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  output$page <- renderUI({
    ui1Output('ui1Output')

  })


  observeEvent(input$login,
               {

                 if(True)
                 {
                   output$page <- renderUI(dashpageOutput)
                  }
                 else
                 {
                   Logged<-F
                   showModal(modalDialog(
                     title = "Error",
                     "Enter Correct Username and password"
                   ))
                 }

               })

})
```

Details: when I going dashboard is showing but not with default skin color or any other skin color. I have tried **skin='red'** like wise option.

[Image for reference how actually showing after login.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpvDM.jpg)

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you open up the console (if using Chrome, it's ctrl+shift+j) and see if it shows any errors/issues? Paste that image here.

Comment: Yes, I have done this also but there is no error but one message is showing as follow.                                                                
     [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
send @ jquery.min.js:4

Comment: @Cool_Ashish Do you got the solution for this issue.